# Why does Go have runtime overhead for range loops over an array?

Tags: go, optimization, iteration

I would expect that doing a range iteration over the elements of an array would not carry any runtime overhead, but it appears to be 8x slower than raw array access:

```
func BenchmarkSumRange(b *testing.B) {
    nums := [5]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        sum := 0
        for i, _ := range nums {
            sum += nums[i]
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkSumManual(b *testing.B) {
    nums := [5]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        sum := 0
        sum += nums[0]
        sum += nums[1]
        sum += nums[2]
        sum += nums[3]
        sum += nums[4]
    }
}
```

Benchmark output:

```
BenchmarkSumRange-8     1000000000           2.18 ns/op
BenchmarkSumManual-8    2000000000           0.28 ns/op
```

This might make sense if it were a slice whose length were not known at compile-time rather than an array, in which case the runtime code would have to involve a loop with bounds checks. But in the case of an array whose size is known at compile-time, the compiler could just swap out the range iteration for manual access given that the overhead is substantial.

Note: I also tried the more idiomatic range loop over elements:

```
sum := 0
for _, el := range nums {
    sum += el
}
```

This is even slower (4 ns/op).

A side question: is this overhead present in other languages like Rust? It seems to be a violation of zero-cost abstraction, and fairly annoying in performance-sensitive contexts if there is no fast alternative to writing out the array accesses manually.

Comment: "I would expect that doing a range iteration over the elements of an array would not carry any runtime overhead," Your expectations are unreasonable.

Comment: @peterSO I wonder if a language like Python has such an overhead as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is good to know. Is there a reason why it would be more difficult than I think for the compiler to substitute in the raw array accesses when the iterable has known size at compile-time given the substantial speedup?

Comment: Careful: the summation *didn't actually happen*. If you [return the sum](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8tYLqu) then it is actually computed too.

Comment: You’re comparing unrolled loop to a regular loop. That’s a well known optimization. You should at least examine assembly output. The unrolled loop may very well be optimized using vectors instructions. All of that is relevant in any language. That’s probably more to do with the specific compiler implementation. If go compiler is lacking in some regard you should file an issue.

Comment: @esote: It's a composite of the language, the language implementation (Go has more than one implementation), the level of optimization, the algorithm, and several other factors. Note that these are microbenchmarks!

Comment: There are infinite ways to optimize code. Some have been implemented in the Go compiler, some have not. If you think there is a widely-applicable and valuable optimization missing from the compiler, you're free to implement and submit it for inclusion in a future version of Go.

Answer (score 1):

First, observe what actually happens in a `for` loop:

```
for i := range sums {
    // your code goes here
}
```

On every iteration, you are incrementing i, which is clearly an overhead.

Why does the compiler not replace it with raw accesses for each iteration you may ask? This would be completely unreasonable, as your binary size would increase drastically.

Consider looping over a normal range. It stores the value in another variable and then accesses it elsewhere.

Actually go's `for` loops are the fastest of many languages, I'm not sure about the exact reason for it but you can get more information in this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/65diA3yTjKQ).

I have checked the `for` loop performance in several other languages like java, python and rust, and all of them were slower than go's implementation.